# Why doesn't the date picker load in my Kendo app?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker

I'm following along the example of how to use the DatePicker widget but it doesn't seem to load correctly on my app. I'm currently doing:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label for="start_date" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Start Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input kendo-date-picker />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't correctly create the widget and only creates a text input box. Does anyone know why this problem could be happening? I would appreciate any insight! 
[image]

Comment: seems to me you are not loading Angularjs or kendo correctly

Comment: hm but I'm correctly able to use `kendo-numerictextbox ` in other parts of my app. Does that make a difference?

Comment: in the same html? can you use the above code to where you successfully used kendo-numerictextbox ? to see if it works?

Comment: @CharlieNg just tried this out- unfortunately it didn't work :( My numberic-text-box is working but the datepicker isn't showing up correctly even when I wrapped them in the same div

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing some markup and/or the app initialization.

Here's a working DatePicker with the markup in your question wrapped in an ng-app div and with the app being initialized in script:

https://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/elURO

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <!-- This is your markup -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="start_date" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Start Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input kendo-date-picker />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of your markup -->
</div>
```

script:

```
angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
});
```